# Problems passing IEnumerables via post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Re-post of a question I asked already with more detail:

I have two ListBoxFors whose SelectList come from 2 IDictionary objects in my ViewModel. When the page initially loads (GET), they populate as expected. When I post however, their values get set to null. Why does this happen? Why is the IDictionary not passed?

For the code in question, the functionality works like this: there are two ListBoxes next to each other. The user can click items in one box, then using a button, move them to the other box. As a result, I can't just re-bind the ListBoxes, since I want to preserve their contents on POSTs. Here's the code:

ViewModel:

```
public int someValue { get; set; }
public IDictionary<int, string> currentCountries { get; set; }
public IDictionary<int, string> availableCountries { get; set; }
```

In my Edit() action, I have the following:

```
IEnumerable<int, string> currentCountries = CountryRepository.GetCountries();
IEnumerable<int, string> availableCountries = CountryRepository.GetCountries();

var model = new ViewModel 
{
   currentCountries = currentCountries,
   availableCountries = availableCountries
}
```

In my Edit(ViewModel model) POST action, I have the following, nothing special right now:

```
return View(model);
```

And my .cshtml for the part in question looks like:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(
   x => x.currentCountries
   new SelectList(Model.currentCountries, "key, "value")
)

@Html.ListBoxFor(
   x => x.availableCountries
   new SelectList(Model.currentCountries, "key", "value")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are PITAs when it comes to model binding. I would avoid them and use something more standard. Also remember that a ListBox sends the list of selected ids to the controller action, so using a dictionary is inappropriate here.

I would go with a view model more like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<int> AvailableCountriesIds { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableCountries { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<int> CurrentCountriesIds { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CurrentCountries { get; set; }
}
```

which could be populated in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Hardcoded the values in order to simplify but in your application
    // you would obviously be fetching those from your repository
    var currentCountries = new Dictionary<int, string> 
    { 
        { 1, "current country 1" },
        { 2, "current country 2" },
        { 3, "current country 3" },
    };
    var availableCountries = new Dictionary<int, string> 
    { 
        { 1, "available country 1" },
        { 2, "available country 2" },
    };

    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        AvailableCountries = availableCountries.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.Key.ToString(),
            Text = x.Value
        }),

        CurrentCountries = currentCountries.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.Key.ToString(),
            Text = x.Value
        })
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(
        x => x.AvailableCountriesIds,
        new SelectList(Model.AvailableCountries , "Value", "Text")
    )

    @Html.ListBoxFor(
        x => x.CurrentCountriesIds,
        new SelectList(Model.CurrentCountries, "Value", "Text")
    )

    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Now when this form is submitted it will bind correctly to the following action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    // model.AvailableCountriesIds and model.CurrentCountriesIds
    // will contain the ids of selected values in each of the two
    // listboxes
    ...
}
```

And you can [download my test project](http://www.mediafire.com/?xp71xf91b808x3j) which illustrates this into action.

Comment: While everything you posted there makes sense to me, after changing it to be basically the exact same...I am still getting null values passed to the HttpPost action. And the _only_ fields that are null are IEnumerables - every other variable has an appropriate value. I'm at a loss.

Comment: @raoul1034, that's very strange. I have tested this code and it worked perfectly fine for me. I will update my answer to illustrate the exact code I used (I removed the repository call and hardcoded values). In the POST action I successfully obtained the `model.AvailableCountriesIds` and `model.CurrentCountriesIds` properties were correctly bound from the request. The `model.AvailableCountries` and `model.CurrentCountries` properties are of course null because their values are never sent to the controller. You need to query your repository if you needed those values back.

Comment: I implemented similar test code to yours in another project, and it worked fine. But for some reason, in this much larger project, something is amiss. The Ids IEnumerables simply aren't getting passed, though I've verified numerous times that they are typed correctly. Frustrating!

Comment: @raoul1034, in situations like this here's what you can do: start stripping parts from your project until you narrow down the problem. Start removing repositories by hardcoding values as I did, remove javascripts, custom routes, custom model binders, ... I am sure you will be able to find the offending code. Unfortunately I don't know how to help you further as I already showed a working example.